# Change the color of the wrap around arrow

Tags: faces, fringe

So I would like to change the color of the arrow that shows the text is being wrapped. Specifically the red arrow shown here:

[image]

I have tried searching myself and the closest I came is finding out the sides are called "fringe"s and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824328/hide-change-emacs-fringe-bent-arrows-due-to-word-wrapping). But where I hit a stump is figuring out the syntax of the function, `set-fringe-bitmap-face bitmap &optional face`.

I assume means something like this: `(set-fringe-bitmap-face 'left-curly-arrow ((t (:foreground "#616161"))))` But my problem is I don't know how to write the correct syntax for a `[face]` symbol. Also I don't even know if this would do what I want which is just to change the color of that red arrow to something that fits my theme.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You might want to file an enhancement request (`M-x report-emacs-bug`) to allow `set-fringe-bitmap-face` to accept a face spec, and not just a face, as its argument (especially since the doc says "*normally `FACE` should specify only the foreground color*"). It should allow a face but also allow a color name, at least one expressed as a foreground face spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know about the color `#616161` as my Emacs version doesn't seem to display a big enough difference in the color for me to see it with my naked eye, but here is an example using "yellow".

```lisp
(defface my-custom-curly-face
  '((t (:foreground "yellow")))
  "Face for fringe curly bitmaps."
  :group 'basic-faces)

(set-fringe-bitmap-face 'left-curly-arrow 'my-custom-curly-face)
```

Comment: Yes, it seems that the `FACE` arg to `set-fringe-bitmap-face` needs to be a face (i.e., satisfy `facep`), and not just a face spec.

Comment: Hey thank you so much, this worked like a charm :).

Comment: Got a little confused looking at the docs thank you for steering me in the right direction. Still getting used to emacs-lisp kind of syntax.