# Set colour/font for markers

Tags: spacemacs, gud, marker

Is it possible to set the colour or font of markers (e.g. the ones set by gud in `gud-display-line` by using `make-marker`). The theme I am using shows markers in a difficult-to-see light gray. I would prefer something very obvious (e.g. red) and potentially also slightly larger.

There is no  information on setting or modifying colour/size in the [gnu elisp manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Markers.html). I'm not sure how this should work.

note: I am using spacemacs. The questions I believe is not specific to spacemacs, but I would also welcome an easy setting for doing this in spacemacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/32028/9970).

Except in your case:

```el
(set-fringe-bitmap-face 'right-triangle 'my-custom-curly-face)
```